# Spring error Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type - Nomatching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Any ideas what is causing this error?

I have been reading around and i think that it is to do with how i have declared the object that is failing (i.e. it has to be declared as an interface) but i dont think i am understanding exactly what is happening. Could someone please provide a clear explanation of what causes the error and how i can resolve it.

Thanks in advance

```
2014-06-23 16:43:12,905 [main] ERROR com.abc.Author.loader.service.duplicate.myProdDuplicateAuthorService - JDUPLICATE - Error processing 198587 Author.
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.abc.Author.loader.model.myProdDuplicate' for property 'myProdDuplicate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.abc.Author.loader.model.myProdDuplicate] for property 'myProdDuplicate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:463)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1097)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:882)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:290)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$IdentifierDerivingDirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:333)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:123)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:51)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:357)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:329)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy103.save(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.Author.loader.dao.common.myProdDuplicateDAO.storeUnequivocalMatch(myProdDuplicateDAO.java:44)
        at com.abc.Author.loader.service.duplicate.myProdDuplicateAuthorService.matchAuthor(myProdDuplicateAuthorService.java:62)
        at com.abc.Author.loader.service.duplicate.myProdDuplicateAuthorService.matchBatch(myProdDuplicateAuthorService.java:43)
        at com.abc.Author.loader.app.myProdDuplicateMatchMain.main(myProdDuplicateMatchMain.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.abc.Author.loader.model.myProdDuplicate] for property 'myProdDuplicate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
        ... 31
```

The object it is complaning about (i.e. 'myProdDuplicate') is part of the composite key of a JPA entity with lots of fields. I managed to figure out that the problem is with the composite key because if i change the composite key to use the @Embedable annotation it works fine.

### Edit

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="AUTHOR_ID")
private MyProdDuplicate myProdDuplicate;

@Id
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;
```

The error occurs at exactly this line (using spring data repository to save to the db):

```
authorRepository.save(listItem);
```

Is there any reason that the above definition will suddenly stop working and produce the above error? Could a spring (spring data) version upgrade cause this?

I am currently using Spring version 3.2.3.RELEASE and Spring data version 1.4.2.RELEASE

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: You are trying to set a property called `myProdDuplicate` in one of your beans.  You have apparently declared the `ref` or the `value` of `myProdDuplicate` as a string but the object expects it to be a `com.abc.Author.loader.model.myProdDuplicate` type of object.  You would need to show us both your spring xml and the structure of the object you are trying to create for us to help.

Comment: It is declared as a type of MyProdDuplicate and it is part of the composite key.